# 'mix: command not found' error when installing Erlang/Elixir using asdf

Tags: erlang, elixir, debian-buster, asdf

## Fast summery:

Installed Erlang/Elixir using asdf in Debian 11.
Getting 'mix command not found' errors.

## Tried:

- Checked compatibility:   https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/compatibility-and-deprecations.html#erlang-otp-compatibility.  Erlang 24.2.1 & elixir 1.13.2-otp-24 seem to be compatible.
- Added path to: /etc/profile.d/elixir.sh like so:

```
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/elixir/1.13.2-otp-24/bin
```

- Checked ~./bashrc path is referenced:

```
. "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"
. "$HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash"
```

- Checked that Erlang & Elixir installed using erl -v & elixir -v.  They're installed.

Any ideas?

### More details for context:

Script I'm using to install:

```
# Install asdf
git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git ~/.asdf --branch v0.11.3
echo '. "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo '. "$HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash"' >> ~/.bashrc 
source ~/.bashrc

# Install dependencies
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y build-essential libncurses5-dev libssl-dev 

# Install Erlang
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install build-essential autoconf m4 libncurses5-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libssh-dev unixodbc-dev xsltproc fop libxml2-utils openjdk-17-jdk openssl libssl-dev
asdf plugin add erlang https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang.git 
asdf install erlang 24.2.1 

# Install Elixir
asdf plugin-add elixir https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-elixir.git 
asdf install elixir 1.13.2-otp-24 

# Install Node.js
asdf plugin add nodejs https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs.git 
asdf install nodejs 16.13.2 

# resource
source ~/.bashrc
```

### Edit: More details:

Installing elixir without using asdf it works.

```
sudo apt-get -y install elixir
```

The problem is I need to install a specific version.

```
sudo apt-get -y install elixir=1.13.2-otp-24
```

...gives error 'Version was not found'

So the problem must have something to do with asdf.

Comment: “Checked **~./bashsc** path is referenced” is a typo or the typo? `s`→`r`.

Comment: It was a typo.  Fixed.

Comment: What does the `ps -p $$` command return in your shell?

Comment: PID TTY          TIME CMD
   2222 pts/5    00:00:00 bash

Comment: What bugs me is `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/elixir/1.13.2-otp-24/bin`, `asdf` does not install anything to `/usr/local/` AFAICT. If `which elixir` returns `/usr/local`, make sure you **do not** have any non-asdf-managed version of elixir installed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove this: `/usr/local/lib/elixir/1.13.2-otp-24/bin` from your PATH, and run [`asdf global`](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_6-set-a-version):

- `asdf global erlang 24.2.1`
- `asdf global elixir 1.13.2-otp-24`
- `asdf global nodejs 16.13.2`

Comment: I gave it a try.  Problem persists.